# Few basic query regarding WCF Session,InstanceContextMode,ConcurrencyMode etc

Tags: wcf

i am very new in WCF. so often gaze for wcf code & article. after viewing many code i 
often stuck for very basic things and got no elaborate discussion for the below question.
so here are my few basic question....and looking for details discussion with sample situation and with sample code.

### Question A

```
if we do not write anything like SessionMode=SessionMode.Required 
then what will be default nature of WCF service. there will be no session

a) SessionMode.Required
b) SessionMode.Allowed
c) SessionMode.NotAllowed
```

just briefly tell me what is the meaning of SessionMode.Required,SessionMode.Allowed
and what is the difference between SessionMode.Required,SessionMode.Allowed?

what is the default session mode?

i have seen people develop wcf service but did not specify anything like session. so just tell me when one should turn on SessionMode.Required or SessionMode.Allowed ?

### Question B

```
what is InstanceContextMode? 
many people use InstanceContextMode Single or PerCall or PerSession ?
```

i just need deep insight when i should go for InstanceContextMode Single or
or PerCall or PerSession ?

tell me briefly when i woul turn on Single what will happen or what will happen in case of PerCall or PerSession ? what is difference between Single or PerCall or PerSession

what is default InstanceContextMode ?

### Question C

```
what is ConcurrencyMode ??
actually what ConcurrencyMode  does.....what it determines??
there are few ConcurrencyMode available and those 
are Multiple,Reentrant and Single

which concurrent mode one should use in what kind of situation. 
what will be the best    choice
```

### Question D

```
what is the meaning of UseSynchronizationContext=false 
when one should turn on UseSynchronizationContext=true 
or when one should go for UseSynchronizationContext=false ?
```

### Question E

regarding operationcontract

```
[OperationContract(IsInitiating=false, IsOneWay=false)]
bool Add_Contact(int sessionkey, string Newusrname);
```

what is the meaning of IsInitiating=false or true. when i should set it true or false ?
what is the meaning of IsOneWay=false or true. when i should set it true or false ?

i belief my question are very basic and lots of scholar every time monitoring this forum.
i hope i will get the best answer in details with many situation like when one should choose which option over other option with few sample code for simulating situations.
thanks

Comment: Nice question. However, it would be better to split this question out into 5 separate questions.